# Implicit conversion with future

Tags: scala, future, implicit-conversion

I've got problem with implicit conversion from DB model to APP model:

```
  override implicit def dbBook2AppBook(book: Book): BookApp = {
      val author = Await.result(authRep.getById(book.authID),1 seconds)
      BookApp(book.id.get, book.title, 
              AuthorApp(author.get.id,author.get.name,author.get.surname), book.available)
  }
```

Basically i want to convert Book to BookApp:

```
case class BookApp(id: Int,
                   title: String,
                   author: AuthorApp,
                   var available: Boolean)

case class Book(id: Option[Int] = None, title: String, authID: Int, available: Boolean)
```

And as you can see my Book class have Author ID, and i want my BookApp to have AuthorApp object inside. What i need to do is to obtain from database Author, while doing conversion from Book. From database through `authRep: AuthorReposiotory` i'm obtaining `Future[Author]`.

My question is, if there is better way to obtain BookApp from convertion without need to use wait for Author object? Any suggestions?

## Edit

For the answer from "Jon Anderson", I can't make conversion from `Future[Book]` to `Future[BookApp]`, because when i'm obtaining more than one row from Database i'm receiving `Future[Seq[Book]]`, then the conversion won't work. Additional information, i still preserve Future in whole application, because when i do conversion i do something like this:

```
  def findBooks(title: Option[String], authorName: Option[String], 
                authorSurname: Option[String], available: Option[Boolean])
                : Future[Seq[BookApp]] = {
    bookRep.findBooks(title,authorName,authorSurname,available)
                      .map(x => x.map( y => y: BookApp))
  }
```

So convertion is done on object by map, but still returned converted unwrapped object. Main problem is wait in convertion, so main question is, how can i get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered thought the types: you can't.

First of all, forget about using implicits in your design until you are more familiar with the languages, they won't help you here. (And forget about *implicit conversion* forever...)

One possible approach here would be stay work inside the `Future` context suing a `dbBook2FutureAppBook(book: Book): Future[BookApp]`.

Converting from a `Future[Seq[Book]]` to `Future[Seq[Bookapp]]` can be done using `Future#flatMap` and `Future.sequence`:

```
val fsb: Future[Seq[Book]] = ...

val fsa: Future[Seq[Bookapp]] =
  fsb.flatMap { books => 
    Future.sequence(books.map(dbBook2FutureAppBook))
  }
```

This answers your question about `Future`, but be aware that this will emit one database query per book in your `Future[Seq[Book]]`, which is a terrible idea. You probably want to write a `Seq[Book] => Seq[Bookapp]` query by hand.

Comment: Could you tell me why should i forget about implicit conversion forever i will be happy :) In this case, where i have different model to connect to database and different where in Application, i think implicit convertion is really great :) And what about magnet pattern? Could you tell why implicit conversion is bad idea?

Comment: Please open new question "When is it considered acceptable to use implicit conversions in my design".

Comment: I am not quite as religious as @OlivierBlanvillain on the horrors of implicit conversion. I think it can be done right, but I do agree that it isn't necessary at all here. And you in particular want to be careful since you seem new to Scala. [This](http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Types%20and%20Generics-Implicits) will help you get started on understanding where implicits are helpful and where they can be dangerous.

Comment: @Vidya but as you can see i'm converting model object to object which will be used in application. What else can i use than implicit conversion? Use explicit conversion everywhere where i need this? I use this because i want my Repositories to see only DB model, and services and controllers to see APP model.

Comment: Honestly, my first choice would be to have only one class that looks like your `BookApp` class (except for that `var`) and make the notion of conversion--implicit or otherwise--moot. For me, the tradeoffs would be worth it. I might even restructure my data model depending on how much of a pain that is. Either way, conversion brings in a lot of complexity for no real gain in my opinion, and @OlivierBlanvillain's solution, while technically correct for your situation, is really suboptimal as he notes.

Comment: @Vidya thanks, its really helpful, but im using slick with H2 database, so i cant have object as db model class, im also using repository service pattern which allows me to change database easily, that is why i need two classes, one for slick an db connection, and one for application for easy use

Answer (score 0):

You should preserve the future all the way into the app layer.  In this case, a `for-comprehension` works nicely...

```
override implicit def dbBook2AppBook(bookFuture: Future[Book]): Future[BookApp] = { 
    for {
       book <- bookFuture
       author <- authRep.getById(book.authID)
       //any other futures needed to create APP model here...
    } yield {
        BookApp(book.id.get, book.title, AuthorApp(author.get.id,author.get.name,author.get.surname), book.available)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know how to make implicit conversion from Future, to Future, case is i don't want to :) Reason is, sometimes i'm obtaining Future[Seq[Book]] from database, then this conversion with Future won't work :) I will add this to question